# How to encrypt/decrypt data with filter in springMVC Web Project?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, encryption, filter

My project is some java web projects which using Spring+SpringMVC+Mybaits framework.Here is a requirement that encrypt some data like user's name,mobile,identify_number in database and post requirement.I have encrypt these colums in database.I add two filter in a project named mobile-project,which provide post service to other people.In the doFilter() method of filter,I replace the servletRequest with my encryptRequestWrapper,which extends HttpServletRequestWrapper.I Override its getParameter() method and encrypt some data in this method.It work well,data has been encrypted/decrypted well.
Now I copy this to other project,It did not work.Here is my filter code:

```
package com.xinrong.web.admin.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class RequestEncryptFilter implements Filter {
    private Set<String> prefixUrls = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String contextPath = filterConfig.getServletContext().getContextPath();
        String ignoreStr = filterConfig.getInitParameter("ignoreReqPrefix");
        String[] ignorePatterns = ignoreStr.split(",");
        for (String prefix : ignorePatterns) {
            prefixUrls.add(contextPath + prefix);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if (!isIgnoreUrl(req)) {
            String requestType = (String) req.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
            if (requestType != null && requestType.equals("XMLHttpRequest")) {
                chain.doFilter(new RequestBodyEncryptWrapper(req), response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(new RequestEncryptWapper(req), response);
            }
            chain.doFilter(new RequestEncryptWapper(req), response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        prefixUrls = null;
    }

    private boolean isIgnoreUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String url = request.getRequestURI();
        for (String prefix : prefixUrls) {
            if (url.startsWith(prefix)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}




package com.xinrong.web.admin.security;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import com.xinrong.service.bank.rongbao.pay.AES;
import com.xinrong.utils.UrlUtil;

public class RequestBodyEncryptWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final byte[] body;

    public RequestBodyEncryptWrapper(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {
        super(request);
        ServletInputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream swapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[100];
        int rc = 0;
        while ((rc = stream.read(buff, 0, 100)) > 0) {
            swapStream.write(buff, 0, rc);
        }
        this.body = swapStream.toByteArray();
        String tmpStr=new String(body,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println("request tmp str:"+tmpStr);
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(body);
        return new ServletInputStream() {

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return bais.read();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        String queryUrl = getRequestPayload();
        return UrlUtil.getEncryptPara(queryUrl, name);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        String[] vals=super.getParameterValues(name);
        if(ArrayUtils.contains(UrlUtil.encryptKeyArr, name)){
            vals[0]=AES.encryptToBase64(vals[0]);
        }
        return vals;
    }

    private String getRequestPayload() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = getReader();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}


package com.xinrong.web.admin.security;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.xinrong.service.bank.rongbao.pay.AES;
import com.xinrong.utils.UrlUtil;

public class RequestEncryptWapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public RequestEncryptWapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestEncryptWapper.class);

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        String[] strs = super.getParameterValues(name);
        if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) {
            return strs;
        }
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(UrlUtil.encryptKeyArr, name)) {
            logger.info("before encrypt:" + strs[0]);
            strs[0] = AES.encryptToBase64(strs[0]);
            logger.info("after encrypt:stri is:" + strs[0]);
        }
        return strs;
    }

}
```

Here is web.xml configuration.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>encryptRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.xinrong.web.admin.security.RequestEncryptFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ignoreReqPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/statics,/main,/login,/investor/getUnAuthStatusPage</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encryptRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

The problem is that when I type "12345678912" as mobile value condition in this page,value of investorVO's mobile attribute is null,
[queryPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Zrd.png)

code in controller method:

```
  * @param
     * @param
     * @param session
     * @return
     * @throws
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "dataGrid")
    @ResponseBody
    public EasyuiDataGrid dataGrid(InvestorVO investorVO, HttpSession session) {
        return investorService.query(investorVO);
    }
```

But if I invalid the filter,value of investorVO's mobile attribute get "12345678912".I guess something in SpringMVC cause this,but I don't know the exact reason.

-- EDIT

Version of SpringMVC is 3.2.8,it not support @requestBodyAdvice @responseBodyAdvice.

Here is web.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>backend</display-name>

    <!-- 设置Spring容器加载配置文件路径 -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- 解决工程编码过滤器 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- added LiYongjie encrypt -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encryptRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.xinrong.web.admin.security.RequestEncryptFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ignoreReqPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/statics,/main,/login,/investor/getUnAuthStatusPage</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encryptRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security配置 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- SpringSecurity 核心过滤器配置 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <!-- <filter> <filter-name>decryptResponseFilter</filter-name> <filter-class>com.xinrong.web.admin.security.ResponseDecryptFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param> <param-name>ignoreResPrefix</param-name> <param-value>/statics,/main,/login,/investor/getUnAuthStatusPage</param-value> 
        </init-param> </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>decryptResponseFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
        </filter-mapping> -->
    <!-- 加载Spring容器配置 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- 加载Log4j配置 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- 加载防止内存溢出监听器 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- 扩展Request作用域 scope="request" 分别是 singleton、prototype、request、session、global 
        session -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring MVC Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:/config/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!--超时 -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Perhaps I know the reason now.SpringMVC wrapper params from request to pojo Objects.Methods getInputStream(),getReader(),getParameter() from request can be invoked only once.I invoke getInputStream() in my RequestBodyEncryptWrapper Class,so when SpringMVC try to getParameter from request,it get null. But I still don't know how to do it.